# Make Joomla header static so always visible

Tags: css, scroll, header, css-position, fixed

a client has asked if he can have the header area of his site static so it is always visible?

I am using the Eris template: http://hogash-demos.com/themeforest/?theme=eris_joomla

My site is: http://www.negotiumrecruitment.co.uk/dev

The top area with the logo, contact info and navigation plus the line below all wants to stay where it is and when scrolled, the whole site moves up and the top area always remains visible.

Thank you in advance.

Paul Walker

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
#rt-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

> An element with a fixed position is positioned relative to the browser
>   window, and will not move even if the window is scrolled

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Edit: seeing the website you proveided, you will also need to change your *#rt-logo* CSS rule. It's currently 'absolute' and should be 'fixed' instead:

```
#rt-logo {
  display: block;
  position: fixed; /* Instead of 'absolute' */
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -470px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

This is because your logo stays outside your header in your template. Normally it would be inside the header and you wouldn't need this.

Comment: You're welcome @PaulWalker. It would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue. Best regards